# Multiple versions of asp.net framework

Tags: asp.net, windows-2000, framework

I have a new installed w2kr2 with asp.net4 - some users need asp.net 3.5 - can I install that without problems and have both versions running?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean Server 2008, since Server 2000 doesn't support .net4

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple different .net frameworks installed with no ill effect. We have an apps that require both 3.5 sp1 and 4 on the same server 2008 box, and everything works just fine together.